# Format to keep leading zero if cell contains formula

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a VLOOKUP (actually an INDEX-MATCH) in an Excel cell.

This resolves ok but the resulting value has a leading zero, which Excel removes.

The standard solution (according to Google) is to format the cell as text, but if I do that the cell displays the formula instead of resolving it.

What format should I use?

This is an example of the formula (if it makes a difference):

```
=MID(INDEX('$save'!M23:M1021,MATCH(B70,'$save'!X23:X1021,0),1),2,99)
```

Thanks

Comment: I would have thought so as well, but this isn't the case. However I have since found that the TEXT function does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is interested, this is how I solved it.

I needed to add the TEXT function into the formula:

```
=MID(TEXT(INDEX('$save'!M23:M1021,MATCH(B70,'$save'!X23:X1021,0),1),""),2,99)
```